# Multiple form submit with one Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms. I want to submit both forms with 1 button. Is there any method that can help me do it?

Example:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="something">
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="something">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I want both forms to be submitted with 1 submit button. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do not you have a single form instead?

Comment: Why not combine the fields into one form? Looks like you are submitting them to same page anyway.

Comment: Give both forms a unique ID each, same goes with the submit button. Then use javascript to detect when the submit button is clicked, and trigger the submission of the forms. You have to write the javascript code yourself, though or go learn javascript.

Comment: You cannot submit two forms separately. The web browser has one process dedicated to viewing that page. When you submit the first form, it will stop the page you left. You can spawn new processes by setting the forms to open in new windows/tabs. Then, you can open one in a new window and then the other with JavaScript. That would be annoying. What you really need to do is learn Ajax.

Comment: You are missing the point. You can separe HTML presentation to looks your single form as two.
Just make one form, and the give optional params depending on what "form" you intend to process

Comment: I would add, learn jQuery (or similar) as well.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer When you trigger submit on a form, the javascript will stop running. It won't submit the other form. The exception is when the form result opens in a new windows/tab.

Comment: @Kainaw, you can use the event object passed to the event handler to prevent the page from reloading, I'm talking AJAX here, though.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Ignoring Ajax (my suggestion also), if you prevent the page from reloading, it won't submit the form data to the server. I've already gone round and round with this in the past - before Ajax made it possible.

Comment: Why people endows messy codes? OP didn't even make clear if it can combine the forms yet. I can't think of a reason to have multiple forms being submitted at once, which means bad practices generating bad behavior and trouble, which then could be avoided along with fantastic solutions.

Comment: so many suggestions guys but no answer that can help solve a problem. If anyone of you know the answer show me with a code example.

Comment: There is actually an answer: **use ajax** seems to be the common sense. If what you're waiting for is **written working code, ready to be copied and pasted**, then you'll be waiting a little longer.

Comment: @Alan Machado... Yes I am waiting for a ready working code but no because I cant code myself but because I can get the Idea on how to code it... An example would be the best as this is just an example form. My actual form is very large and I need to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you submit a form, the current page is stopped. Any activity on the page is stopped. So, as soon as you click "submit" for a form or use JavaScript to submit the form, the page is history. You cannot continue to submit another page.

A simplistic solution is to keep the current page active by having the form's submission load in a new window or tab. When that happens, the current page remains active. So, you can easily have two forms, each opening in a window. This is done with the target attribute. Use something unique for each one:

```
<form action='' method='post' target='_blank1'>
```

The target is the window or tab to use. There shouldn't be one named "_blank1", so it will open in a new window. Now, you can use JavaScript to submit both forms. To do so, you need to give each a unique ID:

```
<form id='myform1' action='' method='post' target='_blank1'>
```

That is one form. The other needs another ID. You can make a submit button of type button (not submit) that fires off JavaScript on click:

```
<submit type='button' onclick="document.getElementById('myform1').submit();document.getElementById('myform2').submit();" value='Click to Submit Both Forms'>
```

When you click the button, JavaScript submits both forms. The results open in new windows. A bit annoying, but it does what you specifically asked for. I wouldn't do that at all. There are two better solutions.

The easiest is to make one form, not two:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='text1'>
    <input type='text' name='text2'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

You can place a lot of HTML between the form tags, so the input boxes don't need to be close together on the page.

The second, harder, solution is to use Ajax. The example is certainly more complicated than you are prepared to handle. So, I suggest simply using one form instead of two.

Note: After I submitted this, Nicholas D submitted an Ajax solution. If you simply cannot use one form, use his Ajax solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that :

button :

```
<div id="button1">
    <button>My click text</button>
</div>
```

js

```
<script>
   $('#button1').click(function(){
       form1 = $('#idIFirstForm');
       form2 = $('#idISecondForm');
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form1.attr('action'),
        data: form1.serialize(),
        success: function( response ) {
          console.log( response );
        }
      });
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: form2.attr('action'),
          data: form2.serialize(),
          success: function( response2 ) {
            console.log( response2 );
          }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pseudo form in the background. No time to write the code, jsut the theory. After clicking submit just stop propagation of all other events and gather all the informations you need into one other form you append to document (newly created via jquery) then you can submit the third form where all the necesary infos are.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into why you want to use only 1 button for 2 forms being submitted at the same time, these tools that will get the input data available for use elsewhere:

Option 1...
Instead of using `<form>` - collect the data with the usual Input syntax.
 ex: `<input type="text" name="dcity" placeholder="City" />` 
Instead of using the form as in this example:

```
<form class="contact" method="post" action="cheque.php" name="pp" id="pp">
  <label for="invoice">Your Name</label>
   <input type="text" id="invoice" name="invoice" />
  <button class="button" type="submit" id="submit">Do It Now</button>
 </form>
```

use:

```
<label for="invoice">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" id="invoice" name="invoice" />
<button type="button" onclick="CmpProc();" style="border:none;"><img src="yourimage.png"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Do&nbsp;It&nbsp;Now</button>
```

Then code the function `CmpProc()` to handle the processing/submittion.
Inside that function use the Javascript form object with the `submit()` method as in...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function submitform() {
    document.xxxyourformname.submit();
   }
 </script>
```

Somehow I suspect making the two forms into one for the POST / GET is worth reconsidering.

Option 2... 
Instead of POST to use the data to the next page consider using PHP's `$_SESSION` to store each of your entries for use across your multiple pages. (Remember to use the `session_start();` at the start of each page you are storing or retrieving the variables from so the Global aspect is available on the page) Also less work.

Answer (score -1):

Look man. This is not possible with only HTML. weither you gether the inputs in one form or else you use jquery to handle this for you.

Comment: How does JQuery submit two forms when submitting a form cancels all operations on the current page (even with JQuery) and starts loading a new page. So, you use JQuery to submit form 1, then nothing happens with form 2. Processing stopped because you submitted the form.

Comment: No man. You need to use ajax to do this. So you could submit both forms.

Comment: Can you show us how with a fake, dummy example with some JQ syntax and pseudocode?

Comment: JQuery is not Ajax. You can use JQuery without Ajax. You can use Ajax without JQuery. If your answer was "Use Ajax", I would agree. However, it is "Use JQuery". That is what I disagree with.

Comment: answer with a code example. I will implement it to see if it works.

Comment: For example    $(':submit').click(function(){$("form").each(function(){ var mytxt= $(this).find("input").val(); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "your url here", data: "the data to send", success: function(result){/*your code here*/}, error:function(e){/* your code here*/} }); }); return false; });